# Can you identify this marine organism?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

I found this in a beach located at [Magnisia District in Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesia_(regional_unit)). I found many more like this stuck in rocks, this however was loose. It was a bit hard and very smooth to the touch. It didn't seem to move.

The date I found this was 3rd of August 2023.

[image: The top view of the organism]

[image: The bottom view of the organism]

Comment: What are your first thoughts? Your first guess? On the name of this marine organism?

Comment: Looks like some kind of sponge or snail/mollusk type animal or plant?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer I believe it's a kidney sponge, although I am not sure.